# Can I have two different operating systems for two different users on a single machine

Tags: operating-system

My computer has two users. So can I install two different operating system for each user?
Just like windows for user1 and ubuntu for user2?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: Maybe read this http://stackoverflow.com/tour. But the answer on you're question is yes. You can install as many operating systems as you want ,but it needs to be on a other partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible with GRUB http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/GRUB
But only if it's not a problem if one user can boot up into the other OS. ( he couldnt do anything because he has no password. )

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. If you use a encryption tool with a secure bootloader like [DiskCryptor](https://diskcryptor.net/wiki/Bootloader), you can even password-protect one operating system and boot into an alternate operating system if the password isn't entered.